# Changing log files location dynamically with SLF4J and independently of logging framework

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

Is there any way I can use SLF4J to only set my log files location at runtime and **independently of logging framework**?

Because I already saw other posts that present a solution, but they are for a specific framework, either logbak or log4j.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. As its name says, SLF4J is a facade to logging frameworks, it doesn't aim at being able to configure these frameworks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The location of the log file is part of the concrete appenders configuration. SLF4J has no knowledge of what happens with logging events after it hands them off to the binding it uses - and it also shouldn't try to interfere.

Since any application should only use one logging implementation at any time, there should still just be one place to configure the log file location, so I'm having a hard time seeing a problem with that. Does it matter whether you configure that location at the logging facade or the implementation? Or were you actually thinking of providing a root location from which each implementation should relatively define its own file (which might be a useful idea, but still not possible)?

Comment: We have multiple projects installed on multiple clients, and not all of them have the logs in the same directory, so my idea was to have the location saved on a database, so that when we release a new version we wouldn't have to remember to change the directory location on the config file.

Comment: @balizeiro So different versions of your deployment are supposed to log into different files? That can be configured once with a [Sifting Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) (just think `version` instead of `userId` in that example). That's probably what you meant with the framework specific solutions you already found, but from what I understand it's closest to what you want to achieve.

Comment: not different versions but different clients log to different locations. So what I was trying to avoid was to have to change the configuration file whenever I do a new installation on a client

Comment: @balizeiro So long as you have some kind of distinguishing attribute between clients (and you'd need that any way), it should be possible to work out a logback or log4j configuration that doesn't have to be changed for each client. Unless of course the location is different for each client and completely arbitrary, but then a (hypothetical) slf4j-based solution would be just as impossible.